# Merge and group only certain array keys into new arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `foreach` loop with an `if` statement inside that creates arrays based on what the string contains.

```
foreach ($dataArray2 as $item) {
    $items = [];
    if(strpos($item, 'your date is') !== false)
    {
        //Converting 22052018 to 2018-05-22
        $month_words = ["may"];
        $month_numbers   = ["05"];
        $item = str_replace($month_words, $month_numbers, $item);
        $item = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $item);
        $insertion = "-";
        $index = 2;
        $index2 = 5;
        $item = substr_replace($item, $insertion, $index, 0);
        $item = substr_replace($item, $insertion, $index2, 0);
        $time = strtotime($item);
        $date = date('Y-m-d', $time);

        $items['date']= $date;

    } else if (strpos($item, 'hat') !== false) {

        $item = str_replace('.', '', $item);
        $items['hat'] = $item;

    } else {

        $items['tshirt'] = $item;

    }

    $dataArr[] = array_filter($items);

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($dataArr);
echo '</pre>';
```

The array looks like this:

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-22
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [hat] => blue
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tshirt] =>  white
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [hat] =>  black 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [tshirt] => cyan
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-21
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [hat] =>  red
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [tshirt] => blue
        )
```

How I need it to look like:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array (
                [date] => 2018-05-22,
                [hat] => blue,
                [tshirt] =>  white,
                [hat] =>  black,
                [tshirt] =>  cyan
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2018-05-21
                [hat] => red,
                [tshirt] =>  blue,
            )
)
```

EDIT: `var_export` format of the input Array:

```
array (
  0 => 'your date is 22 may 2018, Tuesday.',
  1 => 'hat: blue.',
  2 => 'tshirt: white',
  3 => 'hat: black.',
  4 => 'tshirt: cyan',
  5 => 'your date is 21 may 2018, Tuesday.',
  6 => 'hat: red.',
  7 => 'tshirt: blue',
```

EDIT #2: How to break down the arrays inside `content` into x2 chunks like here:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-22
            [content] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => blue
                            [1] => white
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => black
                            [1] => cyan
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => red
                            [1] => blue
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-05-21
            [content] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => blue
                            [1] => white
                        )
```

Comment: Show us what the input array is also in var_export format or json_encoded.

Comment: and your expected result is impossible with two hat and two tshirt keys in the same array

Comment: I'm far from being an expert. I have made some edits to the array structure I need, and added `var_export` output.

Comment: But that var_export is not the input is it?

Comment: The input array is taken from an XPath request and I guess it's not the correct place to post huge scripts at? I mean, you can clearly see that I get the results I need, I just need to re-organize them. Could you please explain how the inputs would help anyone in understanding the situation? Or am I missing something?

Comment: But still, the expected result is impossible. How are you supposed to echo the blue hat? `echo $arr[0]['hat']` but there is two hats. It can't be done. You need to change your expected result to something that is possible.

Comment: I've just thought that it's a good way to go. 
Could you please advice a more practical approach?
I just need to be able to tie hats and t-shirts to dates to be able to fill the database with these values.

Comment: Not what you wanted? What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method creates an array that is possible.
Instead of regex to parse the date I use the lighter date().
And since tshirts and hats are "the same" I use the same method to parse them.

```
$arr = array (
    0 => 'your date is 22 may 2018, Tuesday.',
    1 => 'hat: blue.',
    2 => 'tshirt: white',
    3 => 'hat: black.',
    4 => 'tshirt: cyan',
    5 => 'your date is 21 may 2018, Monday.',
    6 => 'hat: red.',
    7 => 'tshirt: blue',
);

$i =-1;
foreach($arr as $item){
    if(strpos($item, 'your date is') !== false){
        $i++;
        $res[$i]['date'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace("your date is ", "", $item)));
    }else{
        list($key, $val) = explode(": ", $item);
        $res[$i][$key][] = rtrim($val, ".");
    }
}


var_dump($res);
```

output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2018-05-22"
    ["hat"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "blue"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "black"
    }
    ["tshirt"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "white"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "cyan"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2018-05-21"
    ["hat"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "red"
    }
    ["tshirt"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "blue"
    }
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/1F7OU

EDIT i corrected your dates too. both 21 and 22 of may can't be tuesdays.

Comment: Cool trick with `$i` increment. Can you please suggest how to further break down the array so there is a new array inside `content` with `hat` and `tshirt`? So if I have 24 items in total the output would be 12 arrays inside `content` with `hat` and `tshirt`? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure I understand what you mean with the 24 items thing. Can you give an example?

Comment: Edited the question :)

Comment: You mean like this? https://3v4l.org/gqC5b in your example you don't have hat and t-shirt anymore, I assume that is a mistake?

Comment: Isn't quite what I meant but nevermind, I've already solved it with a lot of `if`s and increment tricks like yours. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok. Sorry I couldn't help you more but it's good that you solved it yourself! Good work!